# Copy constructor called on singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton, visual-studio-2012, copy-constructor

I have the following problem. I have a singleton with a getInstance member function that returns an instance. I call this somewhere in code and for some reason VC tries to call the copy constructor. Why is this? How do I fix this?

The header:

```
class FileSystemEntryCollection {
public:
    static FileSystemEntryCollection &getInstance();
private:
    FileSystemEntryCollection();
    FileSystemEntryCollection(FileSystemEntryCollection const&);
    void operator=(FileSystemEntryCollection const&);
}
```

Source file:

```
FileSystemEntryCollection &FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance() {
    static FileSystemEntryCollection instance = FileSystemEntryCollection();
    return instance;
}
```

The following line calls the copy constructor:

```
auto collection = FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance();
```

I've tried to leave in the relevant code, let me know if something else is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
auto collection = FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance();
```

needs to be:

```
auto& collection = FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance();
    ^
```

`auto` on its own is never a reference type.

Comment: This is because the assignment makes a copy of the  FileSystemEntryCollection class, calling the copy ctor.

Comment: @Diederik: There is no assignment.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Isn't 'auto collection = FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance();'
an assignment?

Comment: @Diederik:  No, it is a _declaration_ of a variable, named `collection`, whose type is the type of the expression `FileSystemEntryCollection::getInstance()`, and whose value is initialized to be the result of that expression.

Answer (score 3):

With a different compiler you'll get the same error for the initialization of `instance`.

```
static FileSystemEntryCollection instance = FileSystemEntryCollection();
```

The `=` here calls for copy construction: formally, the compiler creates a temporary (`FileSystemEntryCollection()`), and copies that into `instance`. However, in this situation, compilers are allowed to skip the copy construction and construct the object directly in place. That's what your compiler is doing. But compilers aren't required to do this.

Better:

```
static FileSystemEntryCollection instance;
```

which uses the default constructor to create `instance`.

Comment: Note also that the original expression, as written, must be legal before the compiler can elide the copy constructor; that is, the copy constructor must be accessible at the point of use (and, these days, not declared deleted).

Answer (score 0):

It calls the copy constructor once inside the source file which constructs the static singleton object.

Comment: Correct, but the copy constructor is accessible at that point, so the code is legal. There's no error because VC++ elides the copy construction and constructs `instance` directly in place. Compilers are allowed to elide that constructor, but they're not required to. So the code isn't portable. Better to just default initialize `instance`.

Comment: Although it may elide the copy construction, it should emit an error if the copy construction isn't allowed in that context.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by "the copy constructor is accessible at that point, so the code is legal."